# find contact list in email like facebook

Tags: email, web-crawler

In facebook, when i goto "find friends" page, it tells me to put in my login information for my email, e.g.- yahoo, gmail, hotmail etc. After which it gets all the contacts from my email account. How does it do this? I want to design my own system like this, but am not sure where to start. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your using php, I would recommend [OpenInviter](http://openinviter.com/).  Does most every major email and social network out there.